# How to display a certain number of links along with information

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

How to display a certain number of links along with information?
First code asks me which page to open and how many items to display. But no matter what I do, my links are displayed correctly, but the text is not correct

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = int(input("page: "))
results = int(input("results count: "))

URL = "..." + "page" + str(page)
HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "..."
}

r = requests.get(url=URL, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')


imgs = soup.find_all("img", class_="attachment-game size-game wp-post-image")[0:results]
data = soup.find_all("article", class_="game")[0:results]
for x in imgs:
    x = x["src"]
    for i in data:
        i = i.text
    print(x + i)
```

Comment: Who are "they" asking you which page to open and how many items to display and where?

Comment: Code asks) `print` displays

Comment: [link](https://iwantgames.ru/not-released-pc/)

Comment: @Deprool : link is not accessible at my region. However I have posted an answer please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your iteration logic is wrong.
If you have two lists, so you can use `zip(list1, list2)` and then iterate the same.

```
imgs = soup.find_all("img", class_="attachment-game size-game wp-post-image")[0:results]
data = soup.find_all("article", class_="game")[0:results]

for img, d in zip(imgs,data):
   print(img["src"] + "  " + d.text)
```

I hope this will helps.